# textbox in html

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

  <BR><p><U>Add contact...</U></p><BR>
  Name:          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="firstbox">
  Id.number:     <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="idbox">

  <?php
    session_start();

    $username=$_SESSION['UserID'];
    $s_name=$_GET['firstbox'];
    $s_id=$_GET['idbox'];
    $db = mysql_connect("???????", "???????", "");
    mysql_select_db("???????",$db);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE u_id='$username' and c_id='$s_id'",$db);

    $myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    if(!$myrow) {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts(u_id, c_name, c_id) VALUES ('$username','$s_name','$s_id')",$db);
      header("Location: http://?????/protectedpage.php");
    } else {
      header("Location: http://?????contact1.htm");
    }
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to check if I value is entered in the `firstbox` and `lastbox`, and if Yes, connect to database, but if No, don't insert into database?

And is it possible to limit the total integer in a box, let's say for example, in the `idbox`, if the integer is above 5 (12345, 11234, 99900), don't insert into database?

ok i have tried this but it doesnt work

```
if (($s_id="") and ($_name=""))
{
header("Location: http://at-web2.comp.glam.ac.uk/students/10003088/contact1.htm");

}
else
{
$db = mysql_connect("at-web2.comp.glam.ac.uk", "user_10003088", "Glamorgan1");
mysql_select_db("db_10003088",$db);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE u_id='$username' and c_id='$s_id'",$db);

$myrow = mysql_fetch_row($result);


if(!$myrow)
    {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO contacts(u_id, c_name, c_id) VALUES ('$username','$s_name','$s_id')",$db);

    header("Location: http://at-web2.comp.glam.ac.uk/students/10003088/protectedpage.php");
   }
else{

    header("Location: http://at-web2.comp.glam.ac.uk/students/10003088/contact1.htm");
}
}
```

i added an if statement to check ,

Comment: Is it possible to add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to your code so it doesn't look like complete crap in IE's Quirks Mode? That aside, yes what you're asking is possible, but [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: yeah it is possible, try it out yourself and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: Also, please upgrade to mysqli or PDO statements, the mysql* set of functions have been deprecated in PHP

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. I'd suggest you search for each of those individual questions on SO before asking 3 relatively simple ones in 1 question. We also like to see some evidence that you've attempted something before asking.

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection. Use parametrized queries instead.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to all of your questions is "yes".

Comment: But it DOES answer the question :) :)

Answer (score 0):

1. To check to see if the textboxes are empty, put an If statement for each one (using textbox name instead of "text":

   ```
   $firstbox = $_POST['firstbox'];
   If ($firstbox === "") {
       Echo "firstbox Empty";
   }

   $idbox = $_POST['idbox'];
   If ($idbox === "") {
       Echo "idbox Empty";
   }
   ```
2. To check the value of the idbox, use a similar if statement:

   ```
   $idbox = $_POST['idbox'];
   If (intval($idbox) > 5) {
       Echo "idbox value greater than 5";
   }
   ```